# How do I get Windows XP Professional upgrade to boot directly without having to choose it at startup?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, multi-boot

I installed a Windows XP Professional upgrade onto a computer I'm going to use as a dev server, but whenever I boot up I have to choose between the pro or regular version. Is there a configuration somewhere that I can change so I don't have to choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MS support article is (probably?) right, but there's a nicer way to do this.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> on the keyboard to open *system properties*.
2. Click the tab *Advanced*.
3. In the section *Startup and recovery,* click the button *Settings*.
4. The dropdown list *Default operating system* should contain two entries on yor computer: one entry for each of your Windows installations.
5. Choose the Windows XP Pro installation.
6. Optional: You can set the timeout to maybe just 3 seconds if you like.
7. Click *OK* to close the two windows.

Now, on reboot, the Pro installation should start!

Answer (score 1):

See this microsoft KB article that explains how to do what you're looking for: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289022